# Stream iPhone camera video to a Mac

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, streaming, recording

Is there an app that would let me stream the iPhone/iPad camera to my Mac? I need high quality so it can be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

[Athome Camera](http://www.ichano.com/athomecam/) can do this, however it is mainly marketed as a home monitoring application (camera surveillance).

Answer (score 1):

You could try AirServer this app lets you Airplay to show the screen of your IOS device on your Mac an can also record it in the latest version.